# Changing the contract state while waiting for the Oraclize __callback()

Tags: solidity, oracles

I have a contract that uses Oraclize to query some data. When the query is sent, a global variable `address` is set to the `msg.sender`. This is to be able to interact with the query sender in the `__callback()` function.

However, I have a doubt that, **while** waiting for the `__callback()` to be executed, another address may initiate the query, and the global state variable `address` will be set to that new address, and when the `__callback()` of the first will be executed, it will interact with a wrong address.

Is this a possible scenario? And, if so, how to prevent it? Maybe by linking the `__callback()` to the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a possible scenario?

Yes, it's possible.

> And, if so, how to prevent it?

You have to associate each `msg.sender` value with the ID returned by the `oraclize_query()` call using a mapping, for example:

```
mapping(bytes32 => address) senderAddresses;
```

Then when you call `oraclize_query()`:

```
bytes32 queryId = oraclize_query(<query>);
senderAddresses[queryId] = msg.sender;
```

When the callback eventually arrives, you can get the original `msg.sender` value from the mapping:

```
function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
    require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());

    address originalSender = senderAddresses[myid];

    // Do other stuff with originalSender...

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this, but in order to test it I have created a global state variable address and assigned it the value of senderAddresses[myid]. The result was an address 0x0. I suspect that for some reason the queryId and myid are different.

Comment: I've summarized the issue here, if you could take a look. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60692/oraclize-mismatching-queryid-and-myid